# master page onmenuitemdatabound event fires before page pre_render event?

Tags: asp.net, menu, master-pages

I have a master page with a menu:

```
<asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal"
DataSourceID="HAPSMainMenu" 
MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="3" DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="true" 
StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" 
CssClass="mainMenu" DynamicVerticalOffset="1" 
DynamicHorizontalOffset="0" 
OnMenuItemDataBound ="mainMenu_DataBound" Height="18pt" Width="100%">
```

I want to perform some action on the content page, **after** `OnMenuItemDataBound` is performed in the master page.I tried in the prerender of content page but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/03/08/asp-net-page-events-lifecycle.aspx) OnXXXX of controls comes before Page.PreRender

Answer (score 0):

You might want to raise an custom event from Master upon menudataboune and have your page subscribe to that event.

Or explain more on what is not working and what behavior are you expecting? Any more details?